# IMFCapturePreviewSink with Audio

Tags: audio, ms-media-foundation

The IMFCapturePreviewSink doc

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447865(v=vs.85).aspx)

says it supports **audio** and video.

I've got video working using MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_PREFERRED_SOURCE_STREAM_FOR_VIDEO_PREVIEW

However there is no audio equivalent in mfcaptureengine.h.

I tried adding the streams directly

```
for (DWORD i = 0; i < streamCount; i++)
{
    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> pMediaType = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED_Xb(hr))
    {
        hr = pSource->GetCurrentDeviceMediaType(i, &pMediaType);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED_Xb(hr))
    {
        DWORD dwSinkStreamIndex = 0;
        hr = m_pPreview->AddStream(i, pMediaType, NULL, &dwSinkStreamIndex);
    }
}`
```

Again video only worked.

The audio stream gave no error in this code but after StartPreview was called I got an IMFMediaEvent error of

> hr(0xc00d36b2)(MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST) err(The request is invalid in the current state.)"

Also capturing these same sources to disk works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate [SetSampleCallback method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447873(v=vs.85).aspx) and [IMFCaptureEngineOnSampleCallback interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447851(v=vs.85).aspx)

All others method from IMFCapturePreviewSink relate to the video stream.

Comment: Calling IMFCapturePreviewSink.SetSampleCallback requires a StreamSinkIndex. And AddStream with MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_PREFERRED_SOURCE_STREAM_FOR_AUDIO fails. Adding the stream from the capture source for audio gives no errors but then you also get no OnSample callbacks and video will no longer displays in the hwin.

Comment: So AddStream fails. What is the error ? MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE or MF_E_INVALIDSTREAMNUMBER ? Also did you use MFCreateAggregateSource to combine your audio and video capture ?

Comment: You can not use an aggregate source with the IMFCaptureEngine.
IMFCaptureEngine's Initialize takes in 2 seperate sources IUnknown *pAudioSource and IUnknown *pVideoSource.
It gives you back 1 IMFCaptureSource with GetSource. This IMFCaptureSource contains both the audio and the video streams.

Comment: This gives me no errors
`for(DWORD i=0;i<streamCount;i++)
{
 IMFMediaType* t=NULL;
 pSource->GetCurrentDeviceMediaType(i,&t);
 GUID u=GUID_NULL;
 t->GetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE,&u);
 DWORD i=0;
 if(u==MFMediaType_Video)
 {
  m_p->SetRenderHandle(m_hwndPreview);
  m_p->AddStream(i,t,NULL,&i);
  m_p->SetSampleCallback(i,this);
 }
 else if(u==MFMediaType_Audio)
 {
  m_p->AddStream(i,t,NULL,&i);
  m_p->SetSampleCallback(i,this);
 }
}`

OnSample never gets any audio samples, just video samples.
Also the SetSampleCallback for the video stream breaks the video display.

Comment: Are you sure the Stream is selected : IMFPresentationDescriptor::SelectStream

Comment: Did you try MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_USE_AUDIO_DEVICE_ONLY